# URI segment with . in it gets converted to _

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-url

Hello hi have this issue, I call this url:

```
user_confirm/this.is.fake@gmail.com
```

then use this:

```
echo $email = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

And it outputs:

```
this_is_fake@gmail_com
```

Why?

p.s. this is my config:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@';
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't be passing the email address through the URL, pass an ID or a hash of the email address instead (for security reasons).

Comment: @evolve: don't worry I make the confirmation with an hash and the id of the user, I was testing and encountered this issue since I got puzzled by it I asked here in case some day I will need this.

Comment: What version of Codeigniter are you using? I tested with your settings and cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `system/application/config/config.php` set:

```
$config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

This seems to help for many people.

Source:

- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/114218/P0/
- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/75734/P30/

Comment: Thank you I wasnt' able to find that thread. You saved me a lot of headaches.